# How to fix "this method must return boolean type" error

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have written the following code for a method which is supposed to remove all the occurrences of the given element in an array and shift the remaining elements forward t. I keep getting the compiler error "this method must return boolean type" even though I have returned booleans. I faced this problem before as well but after running the code a few days later, it worked.

Is there really something wrong with my code?

```
public static boolean removeAll(int [] arr, int size, int elem){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      if(arr[i]==elem){
        count++;
        for(int j=i;j<size;j++){
          arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        }
        System.out.println("Number of elements after insertion: "+(size-count));
        return true;
      }
      }
    if(count==0){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: return `false` before the end of the method or whatever you find more appropriate to the task at hand.

Comment: Why do you need `size` as parameter since you wish remove from the whole array...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error is that your method does not return anything when `count` is non-zero. You don't even need a conditional for it - simply use `return count != 0` instead.

However, there are other, more subtle, errors in your code:

- Do not take array length along with the array. You can get the length by calling `arr.length()`
- Returning `boolean` is insufficient for the caller to do anything with the modified array. You need to return the remaining length instead.
- Your code is O(n<sup>2</sup>) because it keeps copying the "tail" portion of the array on each removal. This task can be accomplished in O(n) by maintaining two indexes - one for reading, and one for writing the data.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! it's actually a class assignment to create a method that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The return needs to be level with the function block. You do not need "if(count==0)" because if the java application has already gotten to that code, it means the count is definitely zero - the code stops and returns true in the same block you increase the counter.

```
public static boolean removeAll(int [] arr, int size, int elem){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(arr[i]==elem){
            count++;
            for(int j=i;j<size;j++){
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            }
            System.out.println("Number of elements after insertion: "+(size-count));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, this code will only remove one element from the array and then stop since you are returning true. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains because each of the logical "routes" of your code *MUST* return a boolean.

It means you must now check all your code's paths. What happens when the condition within the last `if` is false? (when `count` is different of 0?).

Currently nothing (or more exactly, you can view as if there was an implicit `return;` placed by the compiler which would only be possible to use if your function had a return type of `void`).

Note: when returning booleans after a simple condition, it is actually more concise to directly write the condition in the return. i.e:

```
 return count != 0;
```